# Solve for ? - undetermined inequality symbol

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

So I was solving a problem in Rudin (chapter 3 #16, to be specific) and I realized how convenient it would be to have  a symbol that represented an undetermined equivalence relationship. As an example I will use the symbol $\sim$.

$\mathbf{Example}$. Suppose we have an expression $A$ that we want to relate to $B$. We then set
$$
A \sim B
$$ and perform an algebraic operation to obtain $A'$ and $B'$.  If this operation involved multiplying both sides by a negative number, we change $\sim$ to $\sim'$. So suppose it did; then we have
$$
A' \sim' B'.
$$  Lets perform another algebraic operation, and suppose again that we multiplied by a negative number.  Then $\sim'$ becomes $\sim$ (since inequalities are the same under two multiplications by negatives), and we obtain $A''$ and $B''$ and thus
$$
A'' \sim B''.
$$  We can continue on in this fashion until we have have done $n$ operations. For simplicity let us suppose that at this point our equivalence relation is $\sim'$.  Then
$$
A^{(n)} \sim' B^{(n)}.
$$  Suppose further that we actually know that $A^{(n)} < B^{(n)}$. Then we can conclude
$$
A > B.
$$  If instead we knew that $A^{(n)} = B^{(n)}$ we would have $A = B$, and if instead we knew that $A^{(n)} > B^{(n)}$ we would have $A < B$.

Does anyone know of a symbol such as this, and if so, are there interesting things to be said about essentially solving for equivalence relations?

Comment: +1 I have had the same thought. I don't think any symbol has been designated, but I agree that it would be useful to have a standard one.

Comment: Perhaps $\overset?>$?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not sure whether the relationship is $<$, $=$, or $>$, I usually use a circled question mark.  In LaTeX, type `\textcircled{\scriptsize ?}`.

I can't seem to do this in MathJax; perhaps the closest would be to type `$\fbox{?}$` to get $\fbox{?}$.